# The string '3/18/09 10:16 PM' is not a valid AllXsd value

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

Obviously the reader doesn't like this format incoming from the response XML.

Wondering if I can reformat this.  Trying to convert to `DateTime` using the following code with my `XmlReader`:

```
reader.ReadContentAsDateTime();
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Xml readers generally expect dates/times in a very specific format; you can use this yourself using `XmlConvert`:

```
string s = XmlConvert.ToString(DateTime.Now);
DateTime when = XmlConvert.ToDateTime(s);
```

If you are using something else, you'll have to read it as a string and use `DateTime.TryParseExact` (or similar) to specify the actual format string:

```
string s = reader.ReadContentAsString();
DateTime when = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "M/d/yy hh:mm tt",
     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If you are using `XmlSerializer`, you could use a shim property to do the conversion - let me know if this is what you are doing...

Comment: The data I was feeding in happened to be 10/29/2012 15:25 and that failed. When I changed it to 10/11/2012 15:25, it worked.

Comment: @MarcGravell, when i try to deserialize some rss feed using `XmlSerializer`, `PubDate` element causes error. how can i fix it?

Comment: @burhan by looking at what the value is coming in as, and handling it appropriately? Alternatively, the core framework includes RSS-targeted classes that may do a better job.

Comment: @MarcGravell, it gives the error `System.InvalidOperationException`.  can you give the codes to fix this manually?

Comment: @burhan not without seeing the xml and your model, no

Comment: pls visit [this link](http://diggthedrazen.com/2011/07/05/xml-deserialization-on-windows-phone/) . my codes use the same algorithm.

Comment: @MarcGravell, did you visit that link? if so, what is the solution? (someone has the same problem in the comments at the end of the page)

Comment: @burhan the solution is, as always, to have xml and a model that match. Sometimes that means you can go direct - you might need to have the dates as a string type (rather than DateTime) and then do additional post-processing on it to parse the time. A random link, however, does not provide the exact xml you are struggling with.

Answer (score 122):

According to the XML [schema](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime) spec, date time values should be in ISO8601 format, e.g., something like

```
2009-03-13T22:16:00
```

Comment: In ruby use `iso8601` method, eg `Time.now.iso8601`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, ISO8601 format should look something like `2009-03-18T22:16:00-05:00`, but David's answer (omitting the timezone) works for me too (whereas the ISO8601 format doesn't). Is this because of a local serialization in the XmlConverter (which therefore doesn't need the timezone)?

Comment: In ISO8601, the timezone is optional, so both my original string and your string are valid ISO8601 date time. According to http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#deviantformats, the timezone is also optional in XML schema. I'm not sure why the time zone version doesn't work for you.

Comment: For php Artisans:) there is `toIso8601String` method in `nesbot/carbon` php lib.

Comment: in php you can use date('c', $time);