# XMLSerializer serialising date error : Is not a valid AllXsd

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

Im using the `XmlSerializer` to serialise objects which contain a datetime property.

This serialises fine with the following an example of the results produced:

```
<GuestUserLinkItemActivity>
<ActivityDateTime>2013-03-06T00:00:00+00:00</ActivityDateTime>
<ActivityMessage>Invitation email sent to guest.</ActivityMessage>
</GuestUserLinkItemActivity>
```

But then when I try and deserialise, again using the `XmlSerializer`, this I get the following error

The string '2013-03-06T00:00:00 00:00' is not a valid AllXsd value. xmlserializer Deserialize

There are a couple of posts I have found with similar issues but non provide a solution to this.

[XmlSerializer: The string '' is not a valid AllXsd value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861779/xmlserializer-the-string-is-not-a-valid-allxsd-value)

[The string '3/18/09 10:16 PM' is not a valid AllXsd value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661881/the-string-3-18-09-1016-pm-is-not-a-valid-allxsd-value/661898#661898)

It most likely to do with the date being stored in format not expected and from one of the articles not in the format expected by the xml specification.  so I expect if I manually amend the date stored I could get it to deserialise it properly.

How can I get the dates stored properly using the `XmlSerializer`.

See bits of copy and pasted code below:

```
public class GuestUserLinkItemActivity
{
public DateTime ActivityDateTime { get; set; }
    public string ActivityMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Serializer class:

```
public static class Serializer
{

    public static T DeSerialise<T>(string contentsToDesrialise)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentsToDesrialise))
            return default(T);

        var xmlSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        var sw = new StreamWriter(stream);
        sw.Write(contentsToDesrialise);
        sw.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;
        var obj = (T)xmlSer.Deserialize(stream);
        sw.Close();
        stream.Close();
        return obj;
    }

    public static string Serialise<T>(T obectToSerialise)
    {
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        var sr = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        sr.Serialize(ms, obectToSerialise);
        ms.Position = 0;
        var sread = new StreamReader(ms);
        var serialisedObjectString = sread.ReadToEnd();
        sread.Close();
        ms.Close();
        return serialisedObjectString;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var guestHistoryList = new List<GuestUserLinkItemActivity>();
guestHistoryList.Add(new GuestUserLinkItemActivity(){
                         ActivityDateTime = DateTime.Now, 
                         ActivityMessage = "Invitation email sent to guest."}
);

var serialisedArray = Serializer.Serialise<GuestUserLinkItemActivity[]>(guestHistoryList.ToArray());
var deserialisedObject = Serializer.DeSerialise<GuestUserLinkItemActivity[]>(serialisedArray);
```

Comment: Please post the code of the class(es) you're trying to serialize/deserialize

Comment: FYI, your streams and StreamReader objects should be in `using` blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to serialize/deserialize an array, try with  `List<GuestUserLinkItemActivity>` - it worked for me:

```
var serialisedArray = Serializer.Serialise<List<GuestUserLinkItemActivity>>(guestHistoryList);
var deserialisedObject1 = Serializer.DeSerialise<List<GuestUserLinkItemActivity>>(serialisedArray);
```

Comment: You are right, For some peculiar reason saving this is a list, rather than an array, seems to produce the expected results. Would be interested to know why.