# What is the correct format for ReadContentAsDateTime XMLTextReader

Tags: c#, datetime, xmltextreader

I am using XMLTextReader to extract information out of a xml file. Now I want to use ReadContentAsDateTime but it always throughs an exception. I already tried 2005.9.26, 2005/9/26 and 2005, 9, 26. Does somebody know the correct format for this?

Comment: try look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661881/the-string-3-18-09-1016-pm-is-not-a-valid-allxsd-value/661898#661898

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661881/the-string-3-18-09-1016-pm-is-not-a-valid-allxsd-value

Answer (score 0):

Note that the [`XmlReader.ReadContentAsDateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readcontentasdatetime.aspx) documentation includes:

> If the content is not typed xsd:dateTime, the reader attempts to convert it to a DateTime object according to the rules defined by the [W3C XML Schema Part 2: Datatypes](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=4871) recommendation

That is [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iso_date_format): `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.hhhhhhh` or `yyyyMMddThhmmsshhhhhhh` (former prefered) using `T` to separate date and time. There are various ways to truncate (don't need to include fractions of seconds) and include time zone information.

Comment: TryParse did a good job. So I just read it as string and converted it which worked also fine for me. Thanks for your response!

Comment: @theknut: `DateTime.TryParse` is locale dependent... be careful with that. Probably better to use `TryParseExact` and specify the inbound format. Even better to use the canonical format for maximum interoperability.