# Serializing key value pairs into xml elements with the key being an attribute

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

Ok, So I am serializing a class into xml to be sent as an HttpResponse.  Part of the data is a list of 'states', and I just can't figure out how to format it they way I need it to be.

Right now the xml response looke like so:

```
<user id="x" date="x" ...>
    <state>
        <state name="Email" />
            <Value>email@mail.com</Value>
        </state>
    </state>
    <state>
        <state name="Level" />
            <Value>0</Value>
        </state>
    </state>
</user>
```

I don't want  elements within one  element, and  to not be its own element, but the value of the state element. I wanted it to look like

```
<user id="x" date="x" ...>        
    <state name="Email">email@email.com</state>
    <state name="Level">0</state>
</user>
```

right now my classes are:

```
[XmlRoot("user")]
public class User {
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [XmlArray]
    public List<State> State { get; set; }

}

public struct State {
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Could someone show me what I am doing wrong?
I cannot change the expected output, the service that is receiving these responses is preexisting and out of my control.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mark the `Value` field of `State` as [`XmlText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltextattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and the `List<State>` field of `User` as [`XmlElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and make a few minor element name changes, like so:

```
public struct State
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlText]
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Name={0}, Value=\"{1}\"", Name, Value);
    }
}

[XmlRoot("user")]
public class User
{
    [XmlAttribute("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("date")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("state")]
    public List<State> State { get; set; }
}
```

By the way, `XmlSerializer` requires `DateTime` field values to be [in a very precise format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661881/the-string-3-18-09-1016-pm-is-not-a-valid-allxsd-value).  If your XML dates are not in this format, you will need to manually parse the field.

Then, when I do:

```
        var newUser = new User() { Id = 1, Date = DateTime.Today, State = new State[] { new State() { Name = "Email", Value = "email@mail.com" }, new State() { Name = "Level", Value = "0" } }.ToList() };
        var newXml = newUser.GetXml();
        Debug.WriteLine(newXml);
```

I get the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<user xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" id="1" date="2014-12-08T00:00:00-05:00">
    <state name="Email">email@mail.com</state>
    <state name="Level">0</state>
</user>
```